# Priority Queue with change priority feature, which keeps elements ordered

Tags: multithreading, data-structures, scheduling, priority-queue

I'm looking for a way to schedule threads by priorities and First-Come-First Serve (FCFS) if two threads have the same priority. I was thinking about using a heap of queues or something like that. The problem is that, even if I implement my own priority queue, the ability to change priorities ruins the order of the insertion to this queue.

To solve this problem I can save the insertion time of each thread, and sort the priority queue also by the insertion time (as a secondary parameter to the primary Priority parameter), but I believe that there is a combination of data structures which can solve the problem without usage of the insertion time.

The complexity should be `O(logN)` (there are some naive solutions with `O(N)` complexity, such as having a regular queue, and iterating the queue whenever we have to pop a thread).

Comment: If this is an OS kernel, I wouldn't go near trying to save the insertion time of each thread - it's too much hassle for not enough gain.  In the uncommon case of someone changing a thread priority, just remove the thread from one queue and shove it on another.  If the priority has increased, put it at the head, if decreased, put it at the tail. Then do a dispatch run to get [number of processors] threads from the highest-priority queue and working downwards and decide how to allocate threads to processors in your usual way.

Comment: I'm getting really confused now :(  A thread added into a queue is guaranteed to have 0 time - it's just now being inserted, so it should go at the back of the queue.  You could use the insertion time from the previous queue it was in, but the thread could have recently been moved from a previous, previous queue...  I don't get this requirement and cannot imagine what it is intended to solve - I will have to think about it some more...

Comment: By saving the insertion time I didn't mean to actually save the time, but to have a counter and give a "time stamp" to each thread when it becomes ready to run and inserted into the queue, so the threads can be ordered by their time stamps. Does it costs too much?

Comment: Well, what I can't understand is that, when a thread becomes ready, (maybe it was sleeping or I/O waiting before), it's time stamp is 'now'.  All the threads, if any, in the queue for that priority will have earlier time stamps so, if FCFS is required, the new thread must go at the end. If it is desired that the thread that has just become ready should go first, (not unreasonable if an I/O inetrrupt has just made it ready), then it cound go at the front of the queue, or perhaps have its priority boosted and put in the next higher prio queue. This, IMHO, makes the actual time stamp redundant.

Comment: Hmm.. are you trying to enforce some real-time guarantee such that , when you change the priority of a thread from another thread, it gets inserted into its new queue in 'time waiting' order?  Why would you want this, and why do you care much about the insertion order?  This 'change priority' wait-time ordered insert will only be necessary when your box is overloaded, (has more ready threads than processors), and a priority is changed.  You really need to inflict this time-stamping on every time a thread becomes ready on the tiny chance it may be needed for a priority algo. that is.. unusual?

Comment: I don't know much of this threads scheduling thing to tell what is common and what isn't. I think that it's reasonable to give a thread it's true "time waiting" place, in order to prevent starvation (or even to much waiting - "semi starvation". If the program uses the scheduler in a way that after some time threads are promoted (their priority is changed, to prevent starvation of low priority threads) saving their "time waiting" order will be a good thing.

Comment: OK, well, if you need a 'waiting time' for an anti-starvation algorithm then, sure, put a tick count into the Thread Info Block when it becomes ready.   An array[priority] of queues can hold the TIB pointers and you can insert threads with a binary search of the queue for its priority by waiting time.  This may improve 'fairness' in those cases where the box is frequently overloaded.  Have you done any simuations or have any theory that demonstrate that this insert algorithm helps?  The cost is more time spent in a critical section of the scheduler on every interrupt/syscall that reschedules.

Comment: +1 for question - this certainly makes me think about thread queues and fair scheduling!

Answer (score 2):

May be I didn't get your problem correctly but you could have a separate list for each priority.
So each thread is added to the corresponding list based on its priority. And since you always add at the end of the list and remove from the head you would have a FCFS behavior.

You could also create a Priority Queue to retrieve the next thread with the lowest priority (O(1) to get next thread and O(logN) to insert. For comparison you could use a combination of priority and insert time of each node.

Comment: This will work only if there is a small set of possible priorities. That most likely is the case here, but doesn't have to be.

Comment: That is exactly how I have always handled priority queues - an array of FIFO queues indexed by priority.  I've never had a requirement for anything more than a small set of priorities.  I've never seen a priority queue of actual threads either, just tasks, (well, OK, inside a multithreaded OS kernel I have seen them).

Comment: Thanks. I actually have a small set of priorities. If I've understood your solution, changing the priority of a thread will put it at the end of it's new priority's list. This is not good beacause I want to save the thread's insertion order (and priority's change doesn't resets it's insertion time).

Comment: @Lior:You could modify and instead of adding to the end, shift the elements to place it in the proper location (according to its insertion time) in the queue.But that shifting will add an O(N) in the insertion time.

Comment: Am I the only one here who does not understand this design/requirement?  'insertion time' - insertion into what?  The new queue, the old queue, the queue it was in before the old one?  I'm completely baffled, maybe I need beer.

Comment: @Martin: Well I'm sorry if I'm not clear enough. The running thread must have the highest priority, and when the scheduler picks a thread to run, it should pick the thread which waited (ready to run) the longest time of all the threads which have the highest priority. The insertion time refers to the time that the thread became ready to run (and was inserted to the data structure of those threads).

Comment: @user384706: If I save the insertion time, I can have a priority queue which is ordered as a secondary criteria by the insertion time, so no operation will take more than O(logN). I just don't want to save the isertion time. But I start realising that I probably have to do so..

Comment: If threads that become ready are put at the back of the queue for their priority then, surely, you will get the behaviour you want - the thread that has been waiting the longest will be at the front of the queue and the thread that has been waiting the shortest, (the newly-ready thread), will be at the back of the queue.

Comment: @Martin: But I don't want them at the back of the queue.. I want them to be inserted in the midlle of te queue, ordered by the ir "waiting time".